# When calculating Z Order, how does one implement BIGMIN and LITMAX for more than 2 dimensions?

Tags: b-tree, space-filling-curve

I'm writing a [UB Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) for fun using a [Z Order Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve#Use_with_one-dimensional_data_structures_for_range_searching). It is currently capable of storing points in any number of dimensions and when queried it performs a naive search between two Z Indexes, filtering and discarding any false positives. I would like to implement `BIGMIN` and `LITMAX` to minimize the number of false positives that it traverses, but I can't seem to find any information on how to implement those in a way that does not limit my tree to storing two dimensional data. For example, both [this whitepaper](http://raima.com/wp-content/uploads/COTS_embedded_database_solving_dynamic_pois_2012.pdf) and [this blog post](http://docs.raima.com/rdme/9_1/Content/GS/POIexample.htm#zdivide) describe their implementation in terms that are heavily tied to working with 2D values.

Is there a dimensionality-agnostic way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

For 2 dimension you can treat the z curve as a base-4 number (quadkey). IMO when you sort the quadkey from left to right it is similar to litmin and bigmin. For n-dimension treat it like a base-n number.